# ifstream sets eof flag when file is opened

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, g++, ifstream

I am trying to read from a text file using ifstream, but for some reason when I use g++ to compile, the eof flag is set before anything is even read from the file. Testing if the file is in fact open does return true. When using visual studio to compile it works correctly. Even when the file "file.txt" exists, the program below prints 1 when compiled with g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    if (file)
        std::cout << file.eof();
}
```

The following is from powershell

```
PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        24.01.2022     12:39             33 file.txt
-a----        24.01.2022     12:39            138 testfile.cpp
-a----        24.01.2022     12:47         130594 testfile.exe


PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> g++ -o testfile.exe testfile.cpp
PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> .\testfile
1
PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> type testfile.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("file.txt");
  if (file)
    std::cout << file.eof();
}
PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> type file.txt
a file with
some text
to test
```

OS is Windows 10. Version info for g++ is given below

```
PS C:\Users\baat2\prosjekter\CPP\testdir> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-11.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-boot-ldflags='-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' 'LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high' --enable-linker-plugin-flags='LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++\ -static-libgcc\ -pipe\ -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high\ -Wl,--stack,12582912'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Comment: Have you copy-pasted the correct code? Is the code you show really the one you run? How do you build the program? How do you run it? Have you tried to rebuild the program from the exact source shown in your question?

Comment: According to [this list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) what you describe should be impossible. As far as I see, only input operations are able to set the eof-bit.

Comment: It is exactly the code I run. I build it on the command line with g++ by typing "g++ -o testfile.exe testfile.cpp". And run it on the command line by typing ".\program". Just the standard stuff.

Comment: Running by using `.\program` or `.\testfile`? Please [edit] your question to include a complete copy-paste (as text) from the console window of how you build and run. Also `type` the source code file first so we can verify it.

Comment: Oops yes .\testfile, not .\program

Comment: Failed to reproduce: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc373a1f7ed12343)

Comment: Please also include the `dir` command and its output to verify that `file.txt` exists. Then also `type testfile.cpp` to verify that it's really the actual program you believe it is. If you feel it's hard to copy-paste the text from the PowerShell window, take a screen-shot showing all commands and all outputs, as a single image.

Comment: Edited to hopefully contain the information needed.

Comment: Now it's a good question, which is why I voted on it (it helps more people see it). Unfortunately I can't answer, I just don't know what the problem might be (and I don't have access to a Windows system at work). Perhaps some bug in GCC / MinGW (assuming you use MinGW)? Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: The only reason I can think of would be a file sharing problem of some sort...

Comment: This is strange. With msvc on Windows and g++ on Linux I get ``0``, as expected. Could you give more details on your OS (Windows 10, I assume?) and compiler (mingw?).

Comment: I edited adding compiler info and OS.

Comment: Have you tried it with a different file? (To eliminate the possibility that the file is locked with an exclusive share by some kind of zombie process?)

Comment: @Dúthomhas A locked file should not be possible to open. And it can be opened by both the program and by the `type` command (which also reads its contents fine).

Comment: What I’m saying is that there are all kinds of constraints you can put on a file in Windows. _Is the file encumbered with such?_

Comment: @Duthomas It doesn't matter which file it is. The result is always the same.

Comment: @churill I said in the post that when I use visual studio it works fine. I assumed this implies it compiles with msvc.

Comment: @Tobias Oh, sorry, I didn't see that :) Your last option is to re-install g++, I guess?

Comment: It could very well be that you have found a bug in the current version of MinGW-w64. This kind of stuff does happen... You should take this issue to the [bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/) and submit a ticket.

Comment: Have you tried running the program from the Windows Terminal (instead of PowerShell)?

Comment: @Dúthomhas Yes the same behaviour happens with cmd. The version is up to date so I suppose I will have to submit a bug report.